# Gradient Background For Label Control Powershell

Tags: winforms, powershell, background, gradient

I am trying to create a gradient background for my label control in powershell. I am able to create the gradient background but the text of the control is covered by the gradient. this is what I have so far:

```
    $label = new-object system.windows.forms.label
    $label.text = "hello"
    $label.forecolor = "white"
    $label.add_paint({$brush = new-object System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush((new-object system.drawing.point 0,0),(new-object system.drawing.point($this.clientrectangle.width,$this.clientrectangle.height)),"black","white")
    $_.graphics.fillrectangle($brush,$this.clientrectangle)
    })
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

[Draw A Gradient On A Label Control](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/d48dab76-794c-4d87-a0c8-24b6743aab39/gradient-background-of-a-label?forum=ITCG) from my question on scripting forms on Microsoft

As I suspected I was covering my label with my graphic so I needed to use the drawstring method to write on top of my graphic I created for the gradient.

```
    $label = new-object system.windows.forms.label
    $label.text = "hello"
    $label.forecolor = "white"
    $label.add_paint({$brush = new-object System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush((new-object system.drawing.point 0,0),(new-object system.drawing.point($this.clientrectangle.width,$this.clientrectangle.height)),"black","white")
    $_.graphics.fillrectangle($brush,$this.clientrectangle)
    $brush2 = new-object System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush((new-object system.drawing.point 0,0),(new-object system.drawing.point($this.clientrectangle.width,$this.clientrectangle.height)),"white","black")
    $_.graphics.drawstring("hello",(new-object System.Drawing.Font("times new roman",18,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::regular)),$brush2,(new-object system.drawing.pointf(20,0)))
    })
```